# Limit offset support for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, limit

I have a project based on SQL Server 2008. There is table with millions of rows, I need to fetch some rows between two dates (there is a column `cdate`), need to output a sheet file for the same, but it's not possible to fetch all rows at once(request timeout problem), so I find a way to break in multiple requests to write on sheet. But for this I need to have a way to select only some rows like limit and offset in mysql. Is there a way to do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Transact-SQL equivalent of `limit` is `top`.

```
select top 100
    whicheverColumns
from
    whicheverTable
where
    whicheverFilteringCriteria
order by
    whicheverDateEtc desc; -- or ASC is default
```

Comment: But I need to select in between rows too,  how can it be done by select top clause??

Comment: The above duplicate link has an answer indicating how you can do this by adding a subquery/CTE containing `ROW_NUMBER() `.

Comment: @underscore_d Or you can use an API cursor to pick up where you left off the previous batch without having to recalculate it. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68280/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith interesting idea, thanks for the link! That would definitely be preferable for large/repeated blocks to avoid rescans.